Programmatically Log In to Power BI Report embedded in a Web App with PRO license
I have created as web application in which users connect with user and password (ASP.NET CORE using authentication with aspnetusers),
I want to include a Power BI report in a page of this web app.
I did it using the link from Power BI service.
Everything worked well, but the user must log in to power bi service when he enters the page
I would like to avoid this.
So I tried to find out how to have the app logging to power bi service in the place of the user.
The first attempt I made was to register the application in Entra ID and use Service Principal to log in.
It worked, but it would have worked in the future for a limited period of time because you need a Power BI Capacity license (which is quite expensive)
We have 5 Power BI PRO licenses.
How do you log in (programally, like I did using Service Principal) using the single user license instead of the service principal?
How should I configure app authorization in Entra ID? Delegate authorization type instead of application?
How should I request the access token?
Thanks for your help
With service principal I wrote the following code this (see below).
What changes do I need in code if I log in with the user's Power BI Pro license?:
    public string GetAccessToken()
    {
        string clientID = "111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
        string clientSecret = "2222222222222222222222222222222222";
        string tenantID = "3333333333333333333333333333333";

        string authority = $https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID};
        string resource =https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api;

        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientID)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{resource}/.default" };
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            result = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string pippo = ex.Message;
        }
        return result.AccessToken;
    }

Thanks for your help
